# Prefill Adaptive payment Paypal lightbox form

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have integrated embedded adaptive payment paypal form on my website. The form opens in a light-box. I need to prefill the fields like Firstname, Lastname, zipcode etc . Here is the screenshot  :
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/833936/b6baa308a8cd1c2b53252035fc5e7e8e

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SetPaymentOptionsAPI](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) which you can use to specify settings for the payment.